# How can I hide the path to the project in the navigation bar in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

How can I hide the path to the project in the navigation bar in pycharm?
That little line is really annoing. Is there a way to hide it?

[image: The image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Menu: `Help/Edit Custom Properties...`
It opens the `idea.properties` file, add to it this lines:

```
project.tree.structure.show.url=false
ide.tree.horizontal.default.autoscrolling=false
```

It applies the changes to all of the projects.